# The most appropriate way to check if PE file in memory dump has already been mapped or "raw"

Tags: windows, parsing, dump, portable-executable

I have a memory dump with different PE files inside. There are two types of PE files:

1. "Raw"/Not mapped - the same as on the disk (probably, program just read/decrypted it in memory).
2. Mapped image. Here we have aligned/increased section/header sizes.

I'm looking for such PE files using signatures MZ + PE + some other checks inside PE header. Later, I'm going to extract them. However, this works fine for "raw" images, but failed on mapped if virtual size is different from the raw size.

My question is: how can I determine with the greatest certainty that I am dealing with raw or mapped image?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a minidump knows which regions of memory are occupied by the modules listed in the minidump.

Comment: @IInspectable nope, it doesn't if it was manual mapping.

Comment: In a mapped PE, the 1st section is always a page further than it's header (e.g. MZ at 0x400000, then first section is at 0x401000). If you have a kernel dump it's actually easier to check the VADs (see [`!vad`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-vad) command) because the sections are specific to loaded binaries.